# Dockerfile error with AWS Elastic Beanstalk; works otherwise, are there differences?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a very basic Dockerfile, like so;

```
FROM williamyeh/java8:latest
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["java"]
```

It is based on William Yeh's slim Java8 image which I need for some other Java apps I want to run.

If I build and execute this on my CentOS box it works fine and runs without issues.

If I upload it to AWS Elastic Beanstalk as part of a zip containing the Dockerfile it doesn't. Now; until recently my Dockerfile pulled all of the rquired Java stuff itself (and was FROM an Ubuntu image) and that *did* work on EB, the only difference was that I changed it to be FROM a different image, which works on my CentOS box, as I said.

The error log from AWS shows this, which really doesn't help me much;

```
 :[{"status":"FAILURE","msg":"
 [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/03build.sh] command failed with error code 1: 
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03build.sh\ncat: 
Dockerrun.aws.json: No such file or directory\ncat: Dockerrun.aws.json: 
No such file or directory\ncat: Dockerrun.aws.json: No such file or
directory\nPulling repository williamyeh/java8\nStatus: Image is up to date
for williamyeh/java8:latest\nSuccessfully pulled
williamyeh/java8:latest\nSending build context to Docker daemon 557.1
kB\rSending build context to Docker daemon 1.114
MB\rSe","returncode":1,"events":[{"msg":"Failed to build Docker image...etc
```

Note that I am not using a Dockerfile.aws.json, nor did I before when it all worked.

So I can only assume that FROM'ing somehow doesn't work in this case but...why? The documentation is very sparse; [Troubleshooting EB](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/troubleshooting-docker.html)

Any tips and suggestions would be welcome

Comment: I also checked if I could docker pull & run the dockerhub container (williamyeh) on the EB instance itself and that also works.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this was subtle...the one thing I didn't include in the question was the inline comment;

```
FROM williamyeh/java8 # comment...
```

This wasn't causing problems on my CentOS base system but it tripped up AWS deployment. Lesson learned; error messages from AWS deployment logs are not always entirely...clear...

Comment: I think it is written in docs that comments must be on a single line and not at the end of end line with a command.